# How to derive std::vector?

Tags: c++11, vector, deriving

I want a class derived from `std::vector` for my operator `[]`

```
template<class T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
    // ?...

    const T &operator[](size_t index) const
        {
            //...
        }

    T &operator[](size_t index)
        {
            //...
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyVector<int> myVec = { 1, 2, 3 };
    //...
}
```

How can I do this deriving all `std::vector` constructors and assigning operators for C++11?

Comment: FYI: publicly Inheriting from `std::vector<>` is super dangerous as it doesn't have a virtual destructor.

Comment: What if I add `virtual ~MyVector() {}`

Comment: that doesn't change anything. As long as `std::vector<int>* x = new MyVector<int>();` is possible, you'll be in trouble. Addind a virtual destructor to `MyVector` doesn't change anything about what a pointer to a `std::vector<>` means.

Comment: Are there ways to make this deriving not dangerous?

Comment: use private or protected inheritance, and make methods available publicly with using declarations.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using inheritance *at all*. What's in the `// ?...` that warrants *expanding* the interface of `vector`?

Comment: @Frank It is stupid 99% of the time to `new` a `std::vector` so it is far less dangerous than it could be.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is a bad idea.

First, because if someone was as silly as to `new MyVector<int>` and then store that in a `std::vector<int>` and then delete through that pointer, you have UB.  But that is a pretty stupid use case; using `new` on `std::vector` is really bad code smell.

Second, because it seems pointless and confusing.

But you can do it.

```
template<class T>
class MyVector : public std::vector<T>
{
public:
  using std::vector<T>::vector;
  using std::vector<T>::operator=;
  MyVector(MyVector const&)=default;
  MyVector(MyVector &&)=default;
  MyVector& operator=(MyVector const&)=default;
  MyVector& operator=(MyVector &&)=default;
  const T &operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        //...
    }

T &operator[](size_t index)
    {
        //...
    }
};
```

now, this *doesn't* support construct-from `std::vector<T>`.

```
MyVector( std::vector<T>&& o ):std::vector<T>(std::move(o)) {}
MyVector( std::vector<T> const& o ):std::vector<T>(o) {}
MyVector& operator=( std::vector<T>&& o ) {
  static_cast<std::vector<T&>>(*this) = std::move(o);
  return *this;
}
MyVector& operator=( std::vector<T> const& o ) {
  static_cast<std::vector<T&>>(*this) = o;
  return *this;
}
```

that covers some last cases.

This won't be completely transparent, but it covers 99.9% of cases.